# Can I still use meat left out in the trunk

Tags: food-safety

I accidentally left meat in the trunk of my car, it's so cold outside it froze, can I still use it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue if the temperature drops? It'd be different if the meat was left out in hot weather.

Comment: it has been cold the whole time the meat froze rock solid

Answer (score 7):

If the ambient temperature outside (and thus in the car) was below 40 F / 4 C the entire time the meat was left out, then yes, it is still safe just as if it had been in the refrigerator (or freezer as the case may be).  If that is not true, discard.

Comment: the temperature has been so cold that the meat froze rock solid, I would hate to have to discard it but at the same time I don't want my family to get sick

Comment: If it really froze rock solid, you can probably infer it was under 40 F.

Comment: yes it has been in the 30's or less thank you for your help

Comment: @Ana Also make sure to inspect for any sign of animals getting in. The trunk of a car is not small animal proof. Hopefully it was sealed in plastic, which you can check for damage.